# Container of Miscellaneous Types - C++

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, generics, containers

So I'm trying to create a "Table" class in C++ with a structure like so:

Table.h

```
class Table
{
private:
    class TableImpl;
    TableImpl* impl;
};
```

Table.cpp

```
class Table::TableImpl
{
private:
    class Row
    {
    private:
        template <typename T>
        class RowDataCell
        {
            T data;
        }
        std::vector<RowDataCell*> data;
    };
    std::vector<Row*> rows;
};
```

The `TableImpl` consists of a `std::vector` of `Row` objects, and each `Row` object consists of a `std::vector` of generic `RowDataCell` objects. The only thing is, I can't create the `std::vector` because I need to provide a template argument for `RowDataCell*`, which will stymie my goals ofhaving a container of miscellaneous objects.

Is there a way using standard C++ that I can accomplish this goal.

Comment: Have a look at boost::any (and drop templates here - although - boost::variant might be an option, too )

Comment: You should never need a container of generic objects.  You can make one, but it would be difficult to use.  Far better is separate containers for each type, or a container of `boost::variant`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two reasonable approaches.

The first is a discriminating union, the other is a type-safe variant of the old C-style `void*` "anything could be here".

I'll first mention two `boost` implementations of them:

`boost::variant<A,B,C>` (and incoming [`std::experimental::variant`](http://www.open-std.org/Jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4218.pdf)) is a discriminating union.  It can store one thing of type `A`, `B` or `C`.  There are various type-safe ways to get the elements out, or perform operations on them via "visiting".  Variant has some restrictions on what types it can hold, and more restrictions depending on how you inject those types.

`boost::any` (and incoming [`std::experimental::any`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/any)) is a type-safe `void*` with value semantics.  Almost anything can be stored in it (`any` requires your object be CopyConstructable), but you can only access it if you know the exact type of thing stored in it, and ask for it.

Writing either one yourself is doable, but I'd recommend using them, or at the least understanding them and cloning a good part of their interface and patterns.

The `variant` can store instances "internally" within itself, and is usually a better approach.  You can emulate it with a `union`, a list of types, and an index into that list, plus a pile of meta programming boilerplate.  Alignment issues are tricky, as an aside.

`any` is easier to write, but still a bit of a challenge.  It is a really basic type erasure object with only a "cast to type X" (via `typeid` or equivalent) and copy exposed.  If you have ever seen `std::function` be implemented, you are half way there.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a standard C++ way to implement tables of records and it can get ugly.  I tried.

Let's assume that a table is a container of records.
A record can contain fields or records.
Fields can be of different types, such as integer, string and BLOB.

The objective, at least for me, was to keep things as generic as possible until the lowest level, the specialized field.  This means that field values are passed by string.

So, here is a simplified model:

```
struct Component; // The base of everything.
struct Record : public Component {
  std::vector<Component *> components;
};
struct Field : public Component {
  std::string  name;
  virtual std::string  get_value_as_string(void) = 0;
};
struct Field_String : public Field;
//... And so on.
struct Table {
  std::vector<Record *> rows;
};
```

The fundamental issue is that every cell of the table can potentially be of a different type.  The table can have limitless columns and rows.

I also recommend reading about databases.  Many database interfaces can resolve the issues of tables.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do what you want. One way is to define a common interface for the types you want to put into the container and then put pointers to that interface into the vector:

```
class RowDataCellInterface
{
public:
    virtual ~RowDataInterface() {}
    virtual std::string toString() const = 0;
    virtual std::unique_ptr<RowDataInterface> clone() const = 0;
};
```

Then you can derive implementations of this interface even in a templated manner:

```
template <typename T>
class RowDataCell final : public RowDataCellInterface
{
public:
    virtual std::string toString() const
    { 
        std::stringstream ss; 
        ss << data; 
        return ss.str();
    }

    virtual std::unique_ptr<RowDataInterface> clone() const
    {
        std::make_unique<RowDataCell>(*this);
    }

private:
    T data;
};
```

Now can put these thingies into a vector like this:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<RowDataCellInterface>>
```

and everything should work fine. To copy the vector you should use the `clone()` member function of your interface. There are several library solutions out there, which help you accomplish what you want. One of them is `boost::variant` which I would suggest. I gave a very detailed answer to a very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18856824/ad-hoc-polymorphism-and-heterogeneous-containers-with-value-semantics/18868277#18868277). Another library solution is `boost::any`, which may look simpler at first, but since in order to do something meaningful with it you have to know the type of the contained thing, which is erased at the moment of access. I would prefer `boost::variant` over `boost::any` most of the time.