# How to write a function which takes different type of arguments?

Tags: c++, inheritance, overloading

I have to classes :

```
template <class T>
class shared_vector 
{
    T data;
}

template <class  T>
class device_vector
{
    T data;
}
```

I want to write a function f which accects any kind of object, be it of type `shared_vector` or `device_vector` and sets some **flags** accordingly.

Now the obvious solution is to go for **function overloading**. But suppose the function f takes 10 arguments which can either be of `shared_vector` or `device_vector`,
I would have to write 1024 overloaded functions.

Another solution is to use a **parent class** `hybrid_vector` from which both the `device_vector` and `shared_vector` inherit from.

**But unfortunately, device_vector code is not in my control.**

How should i solve this problem ?

NOTE : I know typeid (variable).name () can tell the type, but what will be my function declaration and how can I infer type from it ?

Comment: It sounds like you might want the builder pattern to solve this combinatorial explosion.

Comment: What do those various types have in common?

Comment: Or in fact, just an array of super-type pointers.  Given that you don't control the types in question, you could just create your own wrapper types.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth how would you do create an array of super type of both classes ?

Comment: A function with 10 parameters will never be nice. Find a way to reduce the parameter count.

Comment: Use type-erasure and implement ["ad-hoc polymorphism"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18856824/ad-hoc-polymorphism-and-heterogeneous-containers-with-value-semantics).

Comment: What are you going to do with these parameters in the version that takes 10 arguments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be an option to accept `boost::variant<shared_vector<T>, device_vector<T>>`.

Another option is `std::enable_if` :

```
template<typename V>
std:enable_if<
  std::same_type<V, shared_vector<decltype(V::data)>::value |
  std::same_type<V, device_vector<decltype(V::data)>::value ,
  void>::type
foo(V const& vector);
```

Still going to be verbose if you have `V1..V10` but it's just 2*10 checks, not 1024. And of course you can write your own `is_device_or_shared<Vector>::value` to wrap those 2 tests in something slightly more readable.